# PHP Web API Call Not Working

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I have been trying for a while now to connect to my Web API with PHP and getting nothing.

I can connect using C# perfectly and am getting back results. however PHP seems to be a problem for me. I have tried many methods from SO and getting no joy. I'm a C# developer and need to get this PHP code going to PHP developers to connect to our API too.

**Here is my PHP Code.**

```
<?php

try {

$client = new SoapClient("https://api.proactiveclothing.com/wsdl/ProductDataService.wsdl");

class parms {
    function parms($username, $password) {
        $this->wsVersion  = 1;
        $this->id  = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->productId = 0;
        $this->partId  = 0;
        $this->isSellable  = false;
    }
}
    $p = new parms("api@xx.co.za", "xxx");
    $params = array($p);
    $response =$client->__soapCall("getProductSellable",$params);

   echo "<b>PASS</b>" . "<br />";

   echo $response;

} catch(SoapFault $fault) {

   //echo(var_dump($response));
   echo "<b>FAIL</b>" . "<br />";
   echo $fault . "<br />";

}

?>
```

**This is my C# code which works 100%**

```
private string getProductSellable()
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        string SampleXml = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                            <s:Body xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                                <GetProductSellableRequest xmlns=""https://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/"">
                                    <wsVersion xmlns=""https://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"">1.0.0</wsVersion>
                                    <id xmlns=""http://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"">api@xxx.co.za</id>
                                    <password xmlns=""http://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"">xxx</password>
                                    <productId xmlns=""https://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"">Token1</productId>
                                    <partId xmlns=""https://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"">token1</partId>
                                    <isSellable xmlns=""https://www.proactiveclothing.com/WSDL/ProductDataService/1.0.0/SharedObjects/"">true</isSellable>
                                </GetProductSellableRequest>
                            </s:Body>
                        </s:Envelope>";
        try
        {
            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(SampleXml);

            string url = "https://api.proactiveclothing.com/services/Product.svc";

            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webrequest.Method = "POST";
            webrequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "getProductSellable");
            webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                using (WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse())
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return s;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            return webex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I've disabled the authentication on this method call, if anyone wants to give it a try please.

Comment: your php code works fine and i get some results of some products!

Comment: Why are the results are not displaying for me though?

Comment: you could set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the beginning of your php script to display the error message try it and tell us what error message you get

Comment: I get the following error:  Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.  This is pointing to the following line of code  echo $response;

Comment: that's because you echo your $response object. you can display the results by `var_dump($response);`

Comment: Yay!!!!   :)  working fine now.  I'm still learning PHP.  Thank you helping me work this out!

Comment: still learning too. glad my thoughts helped you.